# Convert from utf-8 hex code to character in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

I have the hex code c2ae, how to I convert this to the UTF-8 character: ®. I need a generic and SIMPLE solution for any hex code.

Update: this should work for any utf-8 hex code like d0a6

Answer (score 8):

```
function hexStringToString($hex) {
    return pack('H*', $hex);
}
```

Comment: really strange, can you explain ?

Comment: @danip: pack() and unpack() are PHP's functions for pushing data in and out of binary strings.  `H*` means "any number of hexadecimal octets, high nybble first".  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php.

Comment: If his hex code was instead expressed as %C2%AE what should the value of H* be changed to?

Comment: @chaos could you tell me how can this be done in reverse? I mean give "®" and get "C2AE" . Using the pack function. (Ive read other questions + answers about this, I wanna know how can this be achieved using amazing `pack` function) thnx

Comment: @TechLife `unpack('H*', '®')`, which has the result `array('c2ae')`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you must have found the solution since you asked this 4 years ago, but I hate finding unanswered questions on Google when I am looking for things.

You can create a string that includes hex characters in PHP using:

```
$string = "\xc2\xae";
$string2 = "\xd0\xa6";
echo $string;
echo $string2;
```

Which will output `®Ц`.

The language reference for PHP [is here under header "Double Quoted"].

You are also able to use octal strings using `\22` syntax and in PHP7 unicode code point support was added using `\u` syntax. This one requires having `{}` around the code, as in: `\u{1000}`.

Happy coding!

Comment: Your answer looked promising, but I still can't figure out how to echo ☑ with the http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe0e/index.htm after it so that it forces it to display as plain text rather than an emoji. Do you know? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if you are still looking, but the checkmark in box [ballot box in check on this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark)  should be unicode 2611, so PHP should be able to echo it with `echo "\u{2611}";` Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks. I ended up moving it to SCSS like this `content: "☑\FE0E"` and needed to use EmojiSymbols font (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip#comment73067475_38452396)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install the PHP extension "mbstring". I have XAMPP installed on Windows and everything is installed by default.
Next, we use the function starting with mb_, in our case mb_chr().

example:

```
<?php
echo mb_chr(0x1F621);
?>
```