# Safari mobile does not respect CSS color attribute for HTML entity &#10006;

Tags: html, css, mobile, safari

Bit of a confusing one, the color attribute is respected on the desktop version of Safari but not on mobile.

I tested it on an iPhone 5 (iOS version 9.2.1).

Sample code (first span will appear black on safari mobile):

```
 <html>
   <head>
      <style>
         span { color: white; }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <span>&#10006;</span>
      <span>&times;</span>
      <span>×</span>
   </body>
 </html>
```

and JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/9t3v8846/

Adding !important didn't do anything. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you try using `#FFFFFF` instead of `white`?

Comment: Just tried now, unfortunately same result.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If any poor people come across this.. the way to fix this is to add a variation selector after the entity like so:

`<span>&#10006;&#xFE0E;</span>`

Essentially what is going on under the covers is that the browser decides how to render the HTML entities.

Safari on iOS prefers to use Emoji-like rendering where possible so it ignores the CSS attribute. The variation selector used above specifies that we want to use text-like rendering causing Safari to now respect any color attributes applied to it.

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you very much! This nut made my head ache for a while.

Comment: Nice. Can we do this for escaped characters in CSS? I tried using \fe0e after escaped character, but no joy. Tested on iPad.

Comment: In some Outlook versions, &#xFE0E; displays as a visible character, i.e. a nonprinting rectangle. Using visibility: none has no effect in Outlook. Using display: none; results in mobile Safari not seeing the entity, so the color declaration is not applied. In short -- this doesn't appear to be a useable solution for HTML email.

Comment: This is probably down to outlook's rendering engine. Have you tried a different way of displaying it?

The following is what I had to use to get it to work in ::after content. It's double escaped for me so perhaps either:
\\2716\\fe0e 
or
\2716\fe0e

may do the trick?

Comment: Am I crazy or does IE render the variation selector as a blank square?

Comment: Thank you! BUT- how did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @mikespitz_8 can you please elaborate a bit on this, can you please explain what is this &#xFE0E;  and how did you figure this out, this is interesting.

Comment: I filed a defect with the webkit team and they came back explaining it to me. This is a couple years ago! But if I remember correctly this character: &#xFE0E; tells Safari to not use its default emoji-renderer but to use the text-renderer instead.

This answer explains it a bit better than I can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip

Comment: `<span>©&#xFE0E;</span>` This worked for me, now I can give the © symbol a color on Safari!

Answer (score -2):

If you are using less try this

```
@baseColor: #ffffff;

body {
    color: rgba(red(@baseColor), green(@baseColor), blue(@baseColor), 1);
    color:@baseColor
}
```

Comment: No luck on that either I'm afraid.

Comment: The question has to do with browser specific rendering.

Comment: Just try to test your example. LESS is being finally translated into CSS. Your LESS snippet will finally end up with exactly the same CSS code as provided in question. In fact, your answer says: try the same CSS rule that is provided in your example, there should happen some magic if you will get it translated from LESS instead of just putting it into style tag!