# Show plain text of arrow characters instead of icons

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` and a `ListPopupWindow` Each list items in `ListPopupWindows` is a `TextView`. When click `TextView`, `ListPopupWindow` will be displayed.
Values are `↓↑→←↘↙↗↖`. However, `↘↙↗↖` are somehow replaced with icons. Is there any way to display plain text of `↘↙↗↖` instead of icons???

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `&#xFE0E;` after the arrow character worked for me. So, instead of

```
android:text="↖"
```

use

```
android:text="↖&#xFE0E;"
```

Before / after:

[image] [image]

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38452396/2610837):

> Append the Unicode variation selector character for forcing text,
>   VS15, `&#xFE0E;`.  This forces the previous character to be rendered
>   as text rather than as an Emoji Symbol.

Comment: how to put it in xml? the FE0E part?

Answer (score -1):

you can use `iconify library`,the github is :https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify

it can replace text with icons like `↓↑→←↘↙↗↖.`

this is my case:

[image]

Comment: Maybe the title is not clear enough. I don't want to show icons of `↘↙↗↖` instead, I just want to display characters of `↘↙↗↖`.

Comment: the basic `ListPopupWindow` demo with `ArrayAdapter` . without any icon when popup display . what your code ?