# Prepend or append icon in field of django-crispy-forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have the following field in a Form:

```
<div class="form-group ">
 <div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" id="To" name="To" placeholder="To" type="text"/>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker form-control-feedback"></i>
 </div>
</div>
```

which looks like

[image]

and I am trying to have a similar result using `crispy-forms`.

I tried

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'Title',
                PrependedText(
                    'From',
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>
                    ),
                'To',
                'Date',
                ButtonHolder(
                    Submit('submit', 'Search', css_class='button white')
                )
            )
        )
```

but I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Is it possible to add an icon as PrependedText in `crispy-forms`?
If not, is there any alternative?

(Edit)

Trying

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
                        Field(PrependedText('From', HTML('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>')), placeholder='From'),
                        'To',
                        'Date',
                        ButtonHolder(
                            Submit('submit', 'Search', css_class='button white')
                        )
                    )
```

does not raise any error, but no icon is shown.

Answer (score 3):

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
   Div(HTML('''
       <div class="input-group"> 
         <input class="form-control" id="To" name="To" placeholder="To" type="text"/>
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker form-control-feedback"></i> 
       </div>'''), 
      class="form-group")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @NeErAj . This seems like hardcoding the complete html for that field into crispy-forms, which to me does not make that much sense. Is there not a more elegant way where only modifying the info about the icon itself would be needed?

Comment: Crispy-form is not good for custom form design. You have to use HTML hardcode for design form.

Answer (score 3):

This works with placeholders:

```
self.helper = FormHelper()
self.helper.form_show_labels = False

self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Field(
        PrependedText('email',
                      mark_safe('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>'),
                      placeholder=_("Enter Email"), autofocus="")
    ),
    Field(
        PrependedText('name',
                      mark_safe('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>'),
                      placeholder=_("Enter Full Name"))
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using glyphicons would be using similar unicode symbols:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field(PrependedText('From', '&#x1f4cc'), placeholder='From'),
            Field(PrependedText('To', '&#x1f4cc'), placeholder='To'),
            Field(PrependedText('Date', '&#x1f4c5'), placeholder='Date'),
            FormActions(ButtonHolder(Submit('submit', 'Search', css_class='btn btn-primary')))
        )
```

Problem here is that placer holder is for some reason not working...

[image: placeholder text not visible]

Note also that appending `'&#xFE0E;'` to the unicode symbols to force that it is not rendered to emojis, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38452396/5802289), does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

just use django's mark_safe helper like this:

```python
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
Field(PrependedText('From',
                    mark_safe('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>')),
      placeholder='From')
```