# How do I extract emojis from a string in Flutter?

Tags: android, regex, flutter, dart

I need to extract emojis from a string for this side project I am working on in Flutter

Input:
"Hey everyone "

Output:
""

How do I achieve this?

This is what I have tried so far based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55433185/how-to-detect-emojis-in-a-string-in-flutter-using-dart3) post

```
var emojiRegex = RegExp(
  "r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])'");

getEmojis(String message) {
  print("EXTRACTING EMOJI");
  var output = message.replaceAll(emojiRegex,"");
  print("EMOJI: $output");
}
```

Comment: Check [How to detect emojis in a string in flutter using dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55433185/how-to-detect-emojis-in-a-string-in-flutter-using-dart3)

Comment: Please add the code you used so far to see where the issue is.

Comment: @TamirAbutbul I was trying to use the solution from that link but it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have added the code I have tried so far

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew don't want to remove the emojis, I simply want to remove everything else other than emojis from the string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect emojis in a String in Flutter using Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55433185/how-to-detect-emojis-in-a-string-in-flutter-using-dart)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```dart
String extractEmojis(String text) {
  RegExp rx = RegExp(r'[\p{Extended_Pictographic}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B3}]', unicode: true);
  return rx.allMatches(text).map((z) => z.group(0)).toList().join(""); 
}

void main() {
    print(extractEmojis("Hey everyone "));
}
```

Output:

The `[\p{Extended_Pictographic}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B3}]` regex is taken from [Why do Unicode emoji property escapes match numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64389323) and it matches emojis proper and light skin to dark skin mode chars and red-haired to white-haired chars.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew, this seems to be working for me however I am seeing this warning "Use valid regular expression syntax.", any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @AravindKarthik That looks like a warning produced by [Linter for Dart](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/valid_regexps.html). Not sure if it is going to be fixed there, or if it is possible to deactivate the warning.

Comment: This regex works better than the other recommended in this post. For example, the other one didn't pick up on ❤️, which was a bit surprising.