# Node.js delete discord message if it is not an emoji

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I've been trying to figure this out but have had a hard time. I can't seem to figure it out. How can I make it so that if a message sent isn't an emoji, it will delete it?

Comment: [emoji-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-regex) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I have adapted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45138005/10046076) answer to detect if the message consists entirely of emojis, and if it doesn't, it gets deleted.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (!/[\u{1f300}-\u{1f5ff}\u{1f900}-\u{1f9ff}\u{1f600}-\u{1f64f}\u{1f680}-\u{1f6ff}\u{2600}-\u{26ff}\u{2700}-\u{27bf}\u{1f1e6}-\u{1f1ff}\u{1f191}-\u{1f251}\u{1f004}\u{1f0cf}\u{1f170}-\u{1f171}\u{1f17e}-\u{1f17f}\u{1f18e}\u{3030}\u{2b50}\u{2b55}\u{2934}-\u{2935}\u{2b05}-\u{2b07}\u{2b1b}-\u{2b1c}\u{3297}\u{3299}\u{303d}\u{00a9}\u{00ae}\u{2122}\u{23f3}\u{24c2}\u{23e9}-\u{23ef}\u{25b6}\u{23f8}-\u{23fa}]+$/u.test(message.content)) {
    message.delete();
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could use [emoji-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-regex), as pointed out by [Jakye in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256826/node-js-delete-discord-message-if-it-is-not-an-emoji#comment111864249_63256826).

Comment: Thank you this actually works! However, is there any way for me to also delete messages if they are longer than one emoji?

Comment: @Nico Wait, I made a mistake, you need to replace the `+` on the end of the regex with `{1}`, not `{2,}`.