# How prevent character from being displayed as emoji in CSS 'before' 'content'?

Tags: css

My iPhone is showing this character `✅︎` as a green checkbox instead of a simple grayscale thick check mark.

I'm already aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip) and the strategy of appending the special invisible `\FE0E` character afterwards to tell the browser *not* to display the preceding character as an emoji.

That trick seems to work when I check my Windows 10 Chrome browser in "iPhone" mode using the developer tools.

But when I look on my actual iPhone, the characters appear as emojis.

What am I doing wrong?

**How can I *force* all browsers on all devices to NOT display a character as an emoji?**

Here is my main [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwhal06/tzgrk2ne/) (in addition to similar code included below).

```css
li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li:before {
  content: '\2705';
  position: absolute;
  left: -26px;
  top: -3px;
}

ul.thickCheck li:before {
  content: '\2705\FE0E';
}
```

```html
<ul class="thickCheck">
  <li>Simple grayscale thick check mark item</li>
</ul>
<ul class="emojiCheck">
  <li>Green checkbox item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try copying and pasting the check mark, 
here's one you can use: ✔️

If that doesn't work I'd either use a different Coding Editor, or try coding on a different device.

You could also run you're code through these validators to check for any other occurring errors:

[HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)   [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Hope one of these solutions work!

Comment: Thanks, but my question isn’t specifically about a check mark; I’m trying to handle any given emoji.

Comment: Ok, here's an article that can help you disable the emoji keyboard. [Turn off Emoji Keyboard](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iosapps/how-turn-off-emoji-on-iphone-ipad-how-disable-emoji-keyboard-in-ios-3647389/) You can re-enable the keyboard again once you need it. Hope this Helps!