# Use non-emoji version of unicode character (highcharts and plain html)

Tags: html, css, unicode, highcharts, emoji

Please refer to [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuek3qz4/).

It includes text, both inside a highcharts chart and outside, where the text includes a "sun" character as shown in [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp).  I've also included variants both with and without [variation selectors](http://mts.io/2015/04/21/unicode-symbol-render-text-emoji/) (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38452396/4070848)) to see what difference they make.

Outside highcharts:

```
<p>Embedded: &#x263C; &#x263C;&#xFE0E; &#x263C;&#xFE0F;</p>
symbols.innerHTML = '<p>Added: \u263C \u263C\uFE0E \u263C\uFE0F</p>';
```

Inside highcharts:

```
title: {
    text: 'In highcharts: \u263C \u263C\uFE0E \u263C\uFE0F'
},
```

Now, it seems to depend on which browser you view this jsfiddle as to whether you get a coloured emoji version of the sun symbol, or a plain-text black version... or even *both* versions!

For example, in Chrome on a *Windows desktop* you get the plain version all round:

[image]

... while in Chrome on Android 7 you get part-plain and part-emoji:

[image]

I really don't like that the style of the emoji versions is completely out of my control, particularly when the style clashes horribly with the rest of the page (e.g. the sun symbol is bright orange and the equivalent moon symbol is bright blue).

So I'd like to force the page to use the *plain version* on all browsers in all contexts... any idea how?

It would seem completely crazy to have to resort to using images, because I want the symbols to have the same appearance as the surrounding text, including text colour (which the user can change at will).  And isn't UTF-8 meant to be a *character* encoding rather than an *emoji* encoding?  I have nothing against cute emojis per se, but only in the right context.

Comment: It is not really a Highcharts issue because you will havve the same behaviour in plain html. You can try the answers from this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip If it does not work, you can use pictures instead of emoji and use renderer to render the picture in the correct position. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.image

Comment: @morganfree yes I had already seen that topic, and indeed I linked to the source for one of those answers in my post... basically they rely on "version selectors".  But doesn't seem to make any difference in my context, which made me wonder whether a different solution is required for the highcharts application.  It would seem to be a massive overkill to have to use pictures rather than text... *surely* there must be a way?

Comment: @morganfree I now believe it is actually a highcharts issue, or at least partly.  See my edited post, second example... on an Android Chrome browser the symbols render as plain-text outside highcharts but as emojis inside highcharts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbols appearance depends on the font you use.

Please look at your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8u23n5ag/1/).
I've just changed the font on all elements:

```
* {font-family:serif !important}
```

Any element can have its own font.
It's up to you which font to use. So choose the right one and tune it up.

**Update**

I have to clarify several points:

1. There are **NO** 'safe' or 'unsafe' fonts.
2. Basically font works like a key-value storage `{code1 => glyph1, code2 => glyph2, ...}`, input a code and get the corresponding glyph
3. Font may or may not contain any code-glyph pair
4. You can make your own font containing only desired symbols, having codes of your choice associated with glyphs of your choice e.g. `\u263d` can be any glyph you want, not always the `moon`
5. In css `font-family:` you can specify one or several font-families and/or generic-families ([look here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp)). When the style's being applied to the text the browser converts each symbol (`'A', '&nbsp;' or '\u263d'`) to its code and tries to get the glyph from the specified font-families until the glyph has been found or no more fonts have left.
   If the font contains the desired code-glyph pair we can see a glyph, if not - we can see a space, ?, an outlined rectangle, a rectangle with the code inside, etc. (depends on the browser).

In this case: `{font-family:serif} for \u263d` browser searches for the glyph for `\u263d` in all system fonts of generic-family `serif`. And on Android it firstly finds what you name the 'emoji'.

**The solution** is to find (see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxkedv2k/)) or to make (see the [other jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7z7hueL/1/)) a font with the desired glyphs and apply it to the desired elements.

Hope it's helpful and clear.

Comment: Very helpful.  In the second example, how did you make the font symbols for inclusion in the CSS?  I assume that this would be more data efficient, only including those symbols you need rather than all from the font-awesome font?

Comment: Happy to help! In the second example, the 'sunmoon' font contains 2 symbols only. Comparing to FontAwesome with 675 icons it is **extremely** data efficient! Please take a look at [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) project. I use it to make custom fonts.

Comment: Amazingly useful answer, and kudos for going the extra mile with working examples and extra insight.  Bounty awarded!  Perhaps a brief explanation in the answer itself about how/where to generate the minimal customised font (thanks for the tip re Fontello) would make it completely perfect!  Thanks again, I understand a lot more about this than before... and hopefully others will too.

Comment: And I love how with the embedded font solution, the character codes for sun and moon in the custom font are even the same as for unicode (\u263C and \u263D), so where that custom font is not available it can still fall back on another font which may symbols available for those codes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Kosh Very has hit on something.  Indeed, changing the font-family on all elements to serif does indeed result in the plain symbol being used in highcharts, even in Android 7.  The trouble is, in actual use I cannot stick to a single "safe" font family... the font can be specified by the user, from any web font listed on [Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/).

I've [updated the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brft0w22/) to include loading and use of a web font:

```
// see https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader
WebFont.load({
    google: {
      families: ['Fresca:400']
    }
});
```

And I use that font throughout, both inside and outside highcharts.  The result on Windows Chrome is as before (plain text symbols all over), but now the result in Android 7 Chrome is:

[image]

So this now rather suggests that the issue isn't highcharts-specific after all, and more of a font issue as Kosh Very as indicated.  Indeed in the original example, without any font stated explicitly, the font used in highcharts is different to that used outside... and probably hence the difference in symbol style.

But I've tried a couple of other completely different web fonts in the updated jsfiddle example, with the same result.  In other words, the emoji sun symbol is not apparently coming from the font itself.  Perhaps when a font is missing a particular character (these fonts probably don't have a character for every unicode value) then it reverts to using characters from the system font?  From other discussions it seems that these coloured emojis might only show on Samsung devices, so maybe the system font on Samsung has these?

The solution (or workaround) seems to be use a "safe font" only where required (for the graphical characters), and your desired font elsewhere, as per [this updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a65qbyjr/), which gives the following result on Android 7 Chrome:

[image]

**BUT** I've hit a snag with this solution... it works nicely for the sun symbol as above, but for the very next unicode character (moon symbol) it doesn't... so maybe that symbol is missing from the `serif` font family and it reverts again to system emoji.

[jsfiddle with moon](http://jsfiddle.net/a65qbyjr/1/)

[image]

So the solution is probably still very patchy... maybe only limited to certain symbols.

Even for a font like Cardo that [apparently supports](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263d/fontsupport.htm) the moon character `\u263d`, [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/7c3p1u41/2/) doesn't work in Android Chrome... still get the coloured emoji version rather than the plain version.

Comment: unfortunately you have some confusion and misunderstanding in your investigation. Please read my updated answer and see the jsfiddles with solutions in it. Sorry for being unclear at the first time.