# How to prevent emojis rendering in Edge

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, emoji

I am using HTML entity &#10004; (✔) in various colors to indicate what options are chosen by a user.

As it turns out, MS Edge turns some UTF-8 characters into emojis which make my design unreadable - I can no longer change their colors with CSS.

I found out in another question that replacing &#10004; with &#10004;&#xFE0E; (✔︎) should do the trick, but it does not seem to be working with Edge.

Is there another way to do it, is it impossible, or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you add an example of these emojis?

Comment: For reference, that other question he’s referring to seems to be https://stackoverflow.com/q/32915485/1427878

Comment: If all else fails you can always use svg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding `font-family: "Segoe UI Symbol";` to your css containing the HTML entity.

For example:

```css
span {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
```

```html
<span>&#10004;&#xFE0E;</span>
```

From there you will be able to style your HTML entity. I've tested this on Edge and have confirmed that it works.

---

The thread below addresses this issue you are having:

- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11635143/

Comment: A developer from the Microsoft Edge Team put together this [CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/prometheusTX/pen/vmZzxG) to show how emojis and symbols are handled in Edge. It should work for you. I've also tested it. [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font) might also be helpful.