# How do I force browser to not show me smiley and instead show me unicode of the emoji?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, unicode, emoji

I'm working on chrome `Version 67.0.3396.99` and `mac OS 10.13.5 (17F77)`. In my html, I don't want browser to convert an `emoji` to it's unicode text. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip) answer and it didn't help me much even if I added `&#xFE0E;`. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend to you, search for emojis in this page  [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org),  and then you only need copy and paste the emoji you want to use, make sure, you have 
in your html `head` the `<meta charset="UTF-8">`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 &#x1F600;
 &#x1F60B;
 <p>
  Or just copy the emoji
 </p>
 
</body>
```

Comment: And I didn't get your solution. I've emojis but I want to convert into it's unicode

Comment: @AjayGaur look at this [solution](https://codepen.io/gabrielxm/pen/RJgbBN)

Comment: I want inverse of that. I want browser to print those numbers