# Prevent appended emoji variation if emoji does not support it

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, emoji

I'm trying to plot some emojis but the gender variations that are not supported for that particular emoji are cluttering the chart.
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJOQz.png).

My question is if there is some way I can prevent this behavior and instead just show the emoji without the variation. I want  instead of `‍♀️`.

I'm working from a CSV file that has a single emoji in the format:

```
U+1F645 U+1F3FF U+200D U+2640 U+FE0F
```

What I'm doing now is simply replacing all `U+` with `&#x`, slapping a semicolon at the end and injecting the string into the html.

Comment: Does stripping the gender symbols from the strings not work? U+200D U+2640 U+FE0F is the female gender modifier and U+200D U+2642 U+FE0F is the male one.

Comment: Hi RandomGuy, the only reason I hesitate to do that is because I don't want to lose the gender distinction between emojis altogether. Honeslty, I was just wondering if there would be a solution similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip), where I could just add a selector or something and keep the emoji from adding extra symbols but keep all other variations. Having now looked at my chart on several devices though, I don't think it's that big a deal. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The gender symbols that follow the base emoji *are* the selectors. If you want to keep the gender differences, then ♀️ and ♂️ must stay. I’m honestly not sure why the gendered sequences don’t render correctly on your end because Microsoft’s emoji font has supported them for quite some time now.