# How can I prevent unicode symbol from rendering as emoji when &#xFE0E; doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

Referencing the following question, I am trying to render a unicode character as text rather than emoji, but when I add the entity to the end, it doesn't make a difference for certain characters such as "Black Right-Pointing Double Triangle With Vertical Bar".

Here is the question: [How to prevent Unicode characters from rendering as emoji in HTML from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip)

Here is a jsfiddle demo:

```html
<span>⏭︎&#xFE0E;</span>
<span>&#9197;&#xFE0E;</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hw0dftzv/

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What browsers are failing to honor the appended entity flag?

Comment: Tested in chrome. That's really all that matters for me.

Comment: I tested in several browsers on multiple OSes, but I only see the black and white versions of the symbols.

Comment: Did you try with Windows 10? Perhaps it's an OS issue..