# Font Glyphs in Browsers

Tags: css, text, fonts, webfonts, glyph

Dear stackoverflow Users,

im trying to use a Glyph of a Font on my Website. I want to place "↗ produkte", but the Browser displays The Arrow up as a blue Icon.

What it looks like right now:
[Blue Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMjpN.png)

What i want to Archive, is that the browser displays the arrow of the font kit: [Font Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEcnO.png)

Do you now a Way to archive that? I could place it as a SVG image in the p Tag but is there a Way to Use the Glyph ↗ in the p Tag too?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Unicode characters from rendering as emoji in HTML from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip)

Comment: This helps me, thanks!