Edge Browser on Windows adds (wrong) background color
I have a website, where I added an arrow before the links:


/*** Add icon to links ***/
div.entry-content p a::before {
    content: "\2197";
    padding-right: 2px
}
<div class="entry-content">
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.example.com">example.com</a>
  </p>
</div>



This works fine on Safari (iOS, iPadOS, macOS) and even on Edge on iOS and macOS. Unfortuntely, in Edge on Windows (client and server), the browser „adds“ a background color which makes the look of the website odd.

Any clue what could be done?

Can you include a screenshot of the current output you are receiving? I can't reproduce this on Edge 129.0.2792.79 (64bit) - Windows 11 Pro 23H2 (build 22631.4317) - or revise the snippet to create an actual [mre]? (screenshot)

Did you maybe open the link previously? If so, then it doesn't look odd but rather how a user would expect it. Previously visited links are styled differently than not-visited links by default.

Please [edit] the snippet to add enough relevant code to reproduce the issue. From the screenshot posted a lot more CSS is being applied - Furthermore are you experiencing the same problem if you click the Run code snippet-button?

Thanks for you help. This should not be the case as the link itself "Gechichte" is correctly formatted. You may see the original webpage at https://vbrz.ch

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

Potentially relevant: How to prevent Unicode characters from rendering as emoji in HTML from JavaScript?

Doesn't happen for me on Windows11 Edge. Have you checked any settings you have in Edge, also using the browser devtools inspect facility what exactly is being set, what font is being used?

As mentioned by @Huang and linked by @DBS here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38452396/10594231
This could be fixed by appending the unicode variation selector VS15 to the character which forces it to be rendered as text rather than emoji.
div.entry-content p a::before {
    content: "\2197";
    padding-right: 2px
}

would become
div.entry-content p a::before {
    content: "\2197\FE0E";
    padding-right: 2px
}

Edit: Edge and some versions of Chrome ignore variation selectors for some reason. The below solution is tested and working on Edge, Chrome and Firefox
div.entry-content p a::before {
    font-family: monospace !important;
    content: "\2197\FE0E";
    padding-right: 2px
}

